# About Apache Ignite Monitoring

Tags: datagrid, ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

I Have Build and Deploy Ignite Web Console Locally.And Start Manager Console on http://localhost:9000/ But problem is there no Monitoring Option Available.Can Anybody Explain How To Monitor Apache Ignite Locally via Web Console

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: hello Karl 
I have built it as per documentation available here https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/v1.9/docs/build-and-deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, this is an enterprise feature and not available in the open-source version.

https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/ignite-web-console

> The web console also features cluster monitoring functionality (available separately as GridGain plugin) that shows various cache and node metrics as well as CPU and heap usage.

If you have the enterprise edition, it should be possible to deploy your own instance for monitoring. The following documentation contains more details.

http://docs.gridgain.com/docs/deploy-web-console-from-docker-image

Answer (score 3):

This is catch monitoring tab is only available in grid gain hosted ingite web console.
so frustrating but I also got same issue.

http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Setup-Web-agent-and-Web-console-on-locally-td8341.html

Comment: Thanks you.
is any alternate way available for this problem?